# How to set different color on annotations?

Tags: google-api, annotations, google-visualization

I want to give different `color` and `auraColor` to annotations on google combo chart. Anyone can say if is it posible and how?

This is current options;

```
annotations: {
            stemColor: 'none',
            textStyle: {
                fontName: 'Arial',
                color: 'white',
                auraColor: 'grey',
                fontSize: 11,
                alwaysOutside: true,
            }
        },
```

Also i've tryed this but it doesn't work;

```
annotations: {
             0:{stemColor: 'none',
                textStyle: {
                    fontName: 'Arial',
                    color: 'white',
                    auraColor: 'grey',
                    fontSize: 11,
                    alwaysOutside: true
                }},
             1:{stemColor: 'none',
                textStyle: {
                    fontName: 'Arial',
                    color: 'black',
                    auraColor: 'red',
                    fontSize: 11,
                    alwaysOutside: true,
                 }},
            2:{stemColor: 'none',
                textStyle: {
                    fontName: 'Arial',
                    color: 'blue',
                    auraColor: 'white',
                    fontSize: 11,
                    alwaysOutside: true,
                }}                
        },
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the `series` option...

```
series: {
  0:{
    annotations: {
      stemColor: 'none',
      textStyle: {
        fontName: 'Arial',
        color: 'white',
        auraColor: 'grey',
        fontSize: 11,
        alwaysOutside: true
      }
    }
  },
  1:{
    annotations: {
      stemColor: 'none',
      textStyle: {
        fontName: 'Arial',
        color: 'black',
        auraColor: 'red',
        fontSize: 11,
        alwaysOutside: true,
      }
    }
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Yes this is what i'm looking for. Thank you :)